# Disable contextmenu for a specific container and its children

Tags: javascript

I need to disable `contextmenu` only inside a specific div `#wrapper`and its children, and not the whole page. This is what I'm doing:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    if (event.target.id === 'wrapper') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

.. but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're approaching this the wrong way: you're adding the listener to the `document`, which may be ok, but it's easier to add it to the element itself, and you are checking `event.target.id`, which is the ID of the current clicked element (e.g. a children of your wrapper), not the wrapper.

To make this work you can easily do something like this instead:

```
var myWrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

myWrapper.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution that work fine

```
<div id="wrapper" oncontextmenu="return false">
#wrapper

<div class="childds">
    
</div>
```

Comment: doesnt work on firefox

Answer (score 1):

The code you have in your question works perfectly. One possibility of why the context menu still showed up is that you in fact clicked on a child of `#wrapper`, instead of clicking on the element itself:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    #wrapper

    <div class="inner">
        #wrapper .inner
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working example demonstrating this issue on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9r69pbxf/3/)

You can overcome this by attaching the event handler to the desired element directly instead. This way, right-click events on child-elements will bubble up to `#wrapper`, and thus fire the event as expected:

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('contextmenu', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[Working example on JSfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9r69pbxf/4/)